# Quarkus native compilation error: "No instances of sun.security.provider.NativePRNG are allowed in the image heap"

Tags: aws-lambda, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to compile an AWS Lambda Quarkus Native project.

The compilation gets broken when I try to add and use an HTTP client.

The error is the following:

```
Error: No instances of sun.security.provider.NativePRNG are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use -H:+TraceClassInitialization.
Detailed message:
Trace:  object java.security.SecureRandom
    object sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
    object sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl
    object org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory
    object java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
    object java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]
    object java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
    object org.apache.http.config.Registry
    object org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator
    object org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager
    object org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder$2
    object java.lang.Object[]
    object java.util.ArrayList
    object org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient
    method io.mirko.alexa.home.raspberry.impl.DynamoDBDeviceRepository.getAWSId(String)
```

I have tried using OkHTTP and Apache HTTP Client with no success.

I have also tried the option `--initialize-at-run-time`, with no relevant outcome with any of the following classes:

1. io.mirko.alexa.home.raspberry.impl.DynamoDBDeviceRepository_ClientProxy
2. io.mirko.alexa.home.raspberry.impl.DynamoDBDeviceRepository
3. org.apache.http.impl.client
4. java.security.SecureRandom
5. org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient
6. sun.security.provider.NativePRNG

I have no restriction on which HTTP client to use. Just a usable one in Quarkus Native would be more than enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Did use consider using the MicroProfile REST client as described at [QUARKUS - USING THE REST CLIENT](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client)?

Comment: @SteveC thanks for the comment. Yes I did, and I am using that as a workaround.
More specifically, though, I have 2 issues: I might not be in control of the source code, so it would be nice to have a widely adopted HTTP client to be working with Quarkus (just imagine if I need to use an OAuth library that uses Apache HTTP client). The second issue is that if I do not know the URL in advance, I can not declaratively define my client. Probably there is a lower level component in Quarkus but I could not find them.